# Trying to hang my self-made gymnastics workout machine in my garage

Tags: studs, joists, stucco

I basically made this machine referencing two videos:

1. [Power Moves Training System](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A55WirN-4Kc)
2. [How to Make Your Own Breakdancing Flare Trainer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t2hVAhF6F4Q)

Mine is a tiny bit different than both but same basic design. It's basically as compact as the first one but uses simple items like the second one.

I had also built a 10ft long, 8ft wide, and 10ft tall [structure](http://i65.tinypic.com/311wb41.jpg) that contains several workout items that I can swap out with carabiner clips attached to eyehooks.

[image: Workout structure]

The problem is in this system my legs swing across the whole structure and the crossbeams I placed for support get in the way as they are only 4ft (and some inches) away from me on either side. I should've made the whole structure 10x10x10 so that issue wouldn't exist but I wasn't thinking obviously.

So now I am trying to hang the machine from a joist in the top.

There are two problems:

1) It is stucco and I am unsure if something like this will eventually crack it over time due to movement. If that is the case I have no clue how to prevent such damage.

I've seen solutions such as [this](http://www.arthlete.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/bolt_deep2.jpg?2a71d8) and [this](https://cpconstantlyvaried.files.wordpress.com/2011/09/img_4922.jpg?w=350&h=467) but have no clue how either were accomplished without damaging the stucco or making sure the movement wont damage it overtime.

2) The garage is directly under a room and I have no idea how I would get on the other side of the joist in order to secure it with a nut.

The only easy solution I see is an exposed beam that is still stucco covered but I could put the eye hook horizontally and place the nut after drilling it through the other side. However there is one problem with that as well. There is a garage opening mechanism close to it and I'm afraid that when I use this flare machine it will hit it pretty often if not every time. Thus why I'd prefer using a joist.

Comment: Stucco is just a coating. You drill past it in order to get to the material that the ceiling is really made of (eg. concrete). There are no nuts on the other side, those are all anchor bolts. The metal anchors are necessary for dynamic loads, they don't get lose over time, because if properly mounted they never move in the first place (unlike plastic anchors). Both of the solutions you linked are pretty much the same, the only difference is direct vs indirect.

Answer (score 1):

The first example to support looks like a cement anchor to me. The second would be better in my opinion because you can distribute the weight acrost several joists or trusses with the supports across 2 or more points I don't think wou will have a cracking problem with the stucco but I do think a single point may be strong enough but crack the stucco, plaster or whatever covering, so I would use that option. Several 1/4 lag bolts should support the boards to the ceiling. I like predeilling so the joist dosent crack. Large fender washers will provide additional strength since it will be a vertical pull down on the wood.

Comment: I think it is fine if he is doing some light dancing, as soon as it becomes a gymnastics training mechanism where there is serious torque and jerking say goodbye to ceiling and joists may start turning too.